# Using pgAdmin 4 behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, pgadmin-4

I am using pgAdmin 4 (v. 4.2.6). Is there a possibility to let pgAdmin communicate with the corporate proxy? We have no direct internet access, because all traffic is handled by our corporate proxy. I found no possiblity to define our corporate proxy within the pgAdmin settings.

I tried to define the proxy in the SSH Tunnel settings (added in v. 3.1) and got the error: "*Failed to create the SSH tunnel. Error: Could not establish session to SSH gateway*"

I tried it without any settings and got the error: "*could not connect to server: Permission denied (0x0000271D/10013) Is the server running on host "URL" (IP ADDRESS) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?*"

Is there a possiblity to get pgAdmin running behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Update for all with the same problem: I've ended up using an alternative tool DBeaver, which offers the possibility to use a SOCKS proxy. I've found no solution for pgAdmin.